# Micro controller programming with bluetooth dongle

Tags: pic, bluetooth, pic16f

I have this [USB bluetooth dongle](http://www.ebay.com/itm/301478316330?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) . I want to know is it posible to active this dongle with PIC 16F628a micro controller and communicate with PC. I know this micro controller support serial communication, but I don't know is this application is posible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dongle you mentioned has a USB interface. PIC 16F628a doesn't have one. So they can't directly communicate with each other.

Better idea will be to use a [serial based bluetooth module like HC-05](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1pc-HC-05-6-Pin-Wireless-Bluetooth-RF-Transceiver-Module-Serial-For-Arduino-EA-/262082291601).

[image: BT module]

You can communicate with this modules using serial Tx and Rx. However if you want to use same Tx Rx for uploading code to your micro controller, then you might have to implement software serial on two other pins in order to communicate with the bluetooth.

Search for online arduino tutorials for bluetooth module. You will find a lot. You can implement those with your PIC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Serial and USB communications are defferent thing? Right. So I can't use this Bluetooth device with this MC. Is what you meant?

Comment: http://www.studentcompanion.co.za/usb-communication-with-pic-microcontroller/ If I use this MC will I able to do what I want?

Comment: @Sajitha - Most likely so. This MC has USB interface and you should be able to directly communicate with the BT dongle you posted.

Comment: @Sajitha, Whiskeyjack is saying that you use the Bluetooth dongle in your PC. You use the HC-05 with your PIC. PIC can then communicate with other Bluetooth devices. You then don't need to add a USB port to your PIC.

Answer (score 2):

No. The PIC16F628 does not have a USB peripheral so you cannot interface to your dongle with this micro.  There are PICs with USB peripherals but it may be easier to interface directly to a bluetooth module rather than have the added complication of going through the USB layer. Consider the PIC24 or dsPIC33 ranges.